# Micopolygon Displacemt Issues

Tags: displacement

whenever following along a guide for micropolygon displacement, I encounted a weird issue where everything seems shifted and out of place.
It's supposed to be bricks.
[image]
[image]
[image][image]

Comment: Please use the [edit] link at the bottom of your question (https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXFuK.png) and add images that shows the settings you used

Comment: Plug a texture coordinate + mapping node into the 'Vector' input on the image textures.

Comment: You are using a nightly build of Blender with vector displacement support. The displacement workflow is slightly different, see my answer here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/104471/what-value-does-the-displacement-input-of-the-cycles-material-output-node-expect/104512#104512