# Displace node output

Tags: materials, displacement

I'm trying to figure out more efficient ways of making physically based materials, and I was wondering, how exactly does the "displacement" input on the material Output node function, and how would you use its various features and functions?

Comment: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/render/cycles/materials/settings.html#displacement

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dRzzaRvVDng&t=1783s

Comment: The answer to this question https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/104471/what-value-does-the-displacement-i nput-of-the-cycles-material-output-node-expect  might help