# Displacement with nodes doesn't work, do I need a Displacement modifier?

Tags: displacement

Here is my node setup:[image]

Displacement is on True, and I have a Subsurf modifier. I am rendering with the Cycles Render.

It doesn't displace at all. I am not sure what i am doing wrong.
I do get displacement with the displacement modifier, but I was following a tutorial where this method worked (it was 2.78).

What am I missing/ Does it not work this way?
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) Material output Displacement input doesn't expect a color, it expects a value.  I don't have any idea what multiplying with what looks like .8 gray with a factor of 5 is going to do; that is highly unusual, to say the least.  Instead, use a simple math/multiply node to do this-- Blender will do an implicit RGB->BW conversion.

2) Rendered preview true displacement does not update with changes.  If you make changes to your displacement, you will need to leave and re-enter rendered preview.

3) I would recommend troubleshooting without any image texture plugged into your surface shader, with displacement set to "Both".  This will let you (and us) see if the issue is with the texture/ UV map, or due to some other issue.

Comment: Thank you, that was very helpfull. It works perfectly now. Btw, do you know the stacks stance on questions like these? Is there another recommended place for troubleshooting? Or should I formulate questions like these differently so they fit better?

Comment: @Lichtbringer I don't know SE policy, but if there is one, it's poorly enforced :)  I don't mind questions like this, because it's well formulated enough, but I would recommend doing more Google research first.  For questions where you're not sure if your question is appropriate to SE, you could consider asking other places like Reddit Blender Help or Blender Artists.

Comment: I'm a somewhat new user but I think your question was formed well. You asked a specific question, tried a workaround first, and provided good screenshots. You also gave a good description of some of the related settings. The only thing you could have done better (IMHO) would be to search around the blender docs and existing stack exchange posts to answer it yourself. That being said, you asked a good question, and now the answer here for others to find when they run into the same problem.

Comment: You may find the excellent answer to [this question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/104471/what-value-does-the-displacement-input-of-the-cycles-material-output-node-expect) gives a good idea of exactly what the displacement output socket expects

Comment: Related link: [Getting “experimental” true displacement to work](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/50440/getting-experimental-true-displacement-to-work)