# Material displacement looks slanted to one side in Blender 2.8

Tags: materials, node-editor, displacement

I've used MicroDisplacement before in 2.79 and all worked fine. Now, I have this problem, that all my displacements get slanted like this (see image).

[image]

I am actually following a tutorial for Blender 2.79 step by step and I still get this result. The only thing I found was that the Displacement setting in the Shader tab changed from *True/Bump/Both* to *Displacement and Bump/Displacement only/Bump Only*, but it seems to be working the same way...

[image]

Can somebody help me, tell what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: I found [this answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/104512/35559) helpful on this front.. I think it all still applies in 2.8 ..

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In Blender 2.80 the Material's *Displacement* input socket accepts vectors (blue socket) instead of scalars (grey socket), which gives it more possibilities (look up "vector displacement").

To properly convert a scalar Displacement map, usually a greyscale image, and make it pluggable into the material's Displacement, you need to use a *Displacement* node:

[image]

The *Displacement* node has a "*Scale*" value so that you don't need to use a *Math > Multiply* node.

Comment: Awesome, thank you, that solved the problem!